# Importing a file in the same file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading over some prewritten code and noticed that the code is importing itself. The name and path of the file is modules/handler.py and there is an import statement of 'import modules.handler'. When I comment it out, the code stops working correctly, giving an error of "name 'modules' does not exist", but works fine when it's not commented out. Can someone explain what this import might be doing and why it's needed? I'd be happy to give more info if it's needed, I know the question is a bit odd.

Comment: @KariFox: It may only need `import modules`, not `import modules.handler`; the two are equivalent aside from the latter also ensuring `handler` is an attribute of `modules` (importing it if necessary). Since you're already being imported, the `handler` part shouldn't be needed.

Comment: How are you running the program? Do you execute modules/handler.py directly? Is this code running in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` conditional?

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, that was it exactly! It must be pulling from some of the other files in modules, but doesn't necessarily need to guarantee that itself is being imported.

Comment: The details can get pretty deep into the weeds here. I have just recently been dealing with some code that I want to have work in both Python2 and Python3, as a package, but also doing self-tests. There are some very short versions, such as what @ShadowRanger said, but in general you write `import <blah>` or `from <place> import <blah>` and Python searches for files to import, imports them *if they're not already loaded*, and then sets the global (to your module) name `<blah>` according to the loaded module. You avoid most recursion through the "if" part. The `<blah>` part here sets [cont'd]

Comment: Just to add some more info for later, we're writing automated plugin testing. We use the files in modules specifically for doing logins and error logs, along with setting the browser and production vs staging for each test. These are essentially just predefined functions that are called in each plugin test file later.

Comment: ... [continued] sets `modules` (in the current name space) to a module, and `handler` (in the `modules` name in the current name space) to another module. (I should also add that if you do the import inside a function, rather than at the top level, the `modules` name is set in the *function*'s name space, in the usual way.)

Comment: Thanks torek, that makes a lot more sense.